# How can I make my file reading/writing program faster?

Tags: java, regex, file, io

So I have one large file that contains a bunch of weather data. I have to allocate each line from the large file into its corresponding state file. So there will be a total of 50 new state files with their own data.

The large file contains ~1 million lines of records like this:

```
COOP:166657,'NEW IBERIA AIRPORT ACADIANA REGIONAL LA US',200001,177,553
```

Although the name of the station can vary and have different number of words.

Currently right now I am using regex to find the pattern and output to a file, and it must be grouped by state. If I read in the entire file without any modifications it takes about 46 seconds. With the code to find the state abbreviation, create the file, and output to that file, it takes over 10 minutes.

This is what I have right now:

```
package climate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * This program will read in a large file containing many stations and states,
 * and output in order the stations to their corresponding state file.
 * 
 * Note: This take a long time depending on processor. It also appends data to
 * the files so you must remove all the state files in the current directory
 * before running for accuracy.
 * 
 * @author Marcus
 *
 */

public class ClimateCleanStates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Note: This program can take a long time depending on processor.");
        System.out
                .println("It is also not necessary to run as state files are in this directory.");
        System.out
                .println("But if you would like to see how it works, you may continue.");
        System.out.println("Please remove state files before running.");
        System.out.println("\nIs the States directory empty?");
        String answer = in.nextLine();

        if (answer.equals("N")) {
            System.exit(0);
            in.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to run the program?");
        String answer2 = in.nextLine();
        if (answer2.equals("N")) {
            System.exit(0);
            in.close();
        }

        String[] statesSpaced = new String[51];

        File statefile, dir, infile;

        // Create files for each states
        dir = new File("States");
        dir.mkdir();


        infile = new File("climatedata.csv");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(infile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        line = br.readLine(); 
        System.out.println();

        // Read in climatedata.csv
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Remove instances of -9999
            if (!line.contains("-9999")) {

                        String stateFileName = null;

                        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".* ([A-Z][A-Z]) US"); 
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                        if (m.find()){
                            stateFileName = m.group(1); 
                            stateFileName = "States/" + stateFileName + ".csv";
                            statefile = new File(stateFileName);

                            FileWriter stateWriter = new FileWriter(statefile, true);
                            stateWriter.write(line + "\n");
                            // Progress reporting
                            //System.out.printf("Writing [%s] to file [%s]\n", line,
                            //      statefile);

                            stateWriter.flush();
                            stateWriter.close();

                        } 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Elapsed " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        in.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: don't flush and close state file every time you append 1 row to it, instead save opened filewriters into hashmap<State, FileWriter> to re-use and then close them all together at the end

Comment: create and append to collection of data and then at the end, write once for each state

Comment: While it won't make it directly faster, you should be making every attempt to close your resources properly, see [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: Don't compile the Pattern every time around the loop.

Comment: Removing the close statement helped it out significantly, thanks. Still working on figuring out the HashMap part.

Comment: Brought it down to 2 minutes

Comment: I also brought the Pattern compile to the outside

Comment: Flip `System.exit(0);
            in.close();` to `in.close() System.exit(0);`

Comment: @TameHog whoops good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map` to keep track of the state files rather than closing them each time:

```
Map<String, FileWriter> fileMap = new HashMap<String, FileWriter>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.contains("-9999")) {
        if (m.find()) {
            stateFileName = m.group(1); 
            stateFileName = "States/" + stateFileName + ".csv";
            FileWriter stateFileWriter = fileMap.get(stateFileName);
            if (stateFileWriter == null) {
                stateFileWriter = new FileWriter(stateFileName, true);
                fileMap.put(stateFileName, stateFileWriter);
            }

            stateFileWriter.write(line + "\n");
        }
    }
}

// flush the writers and close once you have parsed the entire file
for(Map.Entry<String, FileWriter> entry : fileMap.entrySet()) {
    FileWriter writer = entry.getValue();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Woah yup that was a lot faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything you don't have to within the loop.  Make a map of files keyed on the filenames, and leave them open.  Write to them as you need to, and don't close any of them until you're all done.  You don't ever need to flush them, either.  You're defeating all the good buffering will do you.  Once you've done that, you can look at making the buffers bigger.